# Using Eliminate in ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.4

I set up a model in ArcGIS 10.4.1 ModelBuilder to use the [Eliminate](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/tools/data-management-toolbox/eliminate.htm) tool. Searching around to do it led me to [Select by Attributes in Model Builder](https://community.esri.com/thread/35416) and [Eliminate in Arcpy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132043/eliminate-in-arcpy), but it just wont work.

I'm doing the following:

- Create a polygon shapefile
- Calculate area for each feature
- [Make Feature Layer](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-feature-layer.htm) to select only features that are below a given size (this I found I have to do, since there is no tool for [Select by Attribute](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/map/working-with-layers/using-select-by-attributes.htm))
- Run [Eliminate](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/tools/data-management-toolbox/eliminate.htm)

This is a snapshot of the model I set up: [image]

Each time, the model stops when trying to start [Eliminate](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/tools/data-management-toolbox/eliminate.htm), saying:

```
Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000156: Input must be a feature class
```

The tool needs a feature class with a selection, so I think I'm missing something when trying to select the features.

---

I use an iterator to run this without letting the intermediate products load into ArcGIS.

Is it possible that this causes the problem, since ArcGIS is not aware of the layer?

**SOLUTION:** That was it. Must add [Make Feature Layer](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-feature-layer.htm) without any parameter, followed by [Select Layer By Attribute](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/tools/data-management-toolbox/select-layer-by-attribute.htm).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use SelectByAttributed in ModelBuilder as follows:

IF YOUR SHAPEFILE NOT IN TOC:

add Make Feature Layer and just define the input shapefile, don't define the other parameters.

Add select by attributes and define your size
[image]

Result of selected attributed:
[image]

It works perfectly, the result:

[image]

Also, if you want to get a shapefile with your selected attributes only; you can use the Select tool to your Model, then you define your shapefile and size required, and the result is a new shapefile with the selected attributed only. Which you can use it further in your Model.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does the shapefile need to be loaded into the TOC when starting the model?

Comment: Yes in case of select by attribute tool

Comment: I will update my answer if your shapefile not in TOC

Comment: please re-check the edited answer, now it works even your shapefile not in TOC

Answer (score 2):

I replicated your setup in Model Builder. I have a polygon with areas I would like to incorporate into larger Polygons. Using the Selected Layer By Attribute Tool I set the expression to the area criteria I wanted and Used the Eliminate Tool to perform the operation.

Here is the model view:

[image]

Here is the "Select by Attributes"

[image]

Here is the final step, the "Eliminate"

[image]

The model ran and the output was as expected.

I think for your model you won't need the "Make Feature Layer" Tool.